# Calculating $f'(x)$ while $f(x)=$ $\int_{0}^{x^2-3x} (2 + \sin t^2)\,dt$.

Tags: calculus, integration

How to calculate $f'(x)$ while $f(x)=$ $\int_{0}^{x^2-3x} (2 + \sin t^2)\,dt$?

I tried to use the fundamental theorem of calculus by doing the following:

Let $F(x)$ =  $\int_{0}^{x} (2 + \sin t^2)\,dt$.

$f(x) = F(x^2-3x) -F(0) $

then $f'(x)$ = $F'(x^2-3x)(2x-3) - F'(0)$

then said that by the fundamental theorem of calculus $\int_{0}^{x} (2 + \sin t^2)\,dt$.

thus $F'(x)$ = $2+\sin(x^2)$. and I substituted this in: $f'(x)$ = $F'(x^2-3x)(2x-3) - F'(0)$

but for somehow the answer I got isn't right. What is my mistake?

Comment: Take in mind that $(F(0))'=F'(0)\cdot 0=0$

Comment: I like to assign the integrand a different function name. So say we called $2+sin^2(t)=g(t)$ Then we would let $G'=g$ So at your end there  you can say $f'(x)=G'(x^2-3x) \cdot (x^2-3x)'-G'(0) \cdot (0)'=g(x^2-2x) \cdot (x^2-3x)' $

Comment: I think there's an abuse of notation, some of us are thinking $sint^2$ refers to $Sin^2(t)$ and others $Sin(t^2)$. Which one are you referring?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD $F(0)$ is constant, so its derivative with respect to $x$ is zero without any computation. Besides, it's $0$ anyway.

Comment: That is essentially "Leibniz's rule":

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right in considering
$$
F(x)=\int_0^x(2+\sin t^2)\,dt
$$
so
$$
f(x)=F(x^2-3x)
$$
Therefore, by the chain rule,
$$
f'(x)=F'(x^2-3x)\cdot(2x-3)=
(2+\sin((x^2-3x)^2)(2x-3)
$$

Note that $F(0)=0$ by definition. In any case, it is a constant, so it disappears in the derivative.

Comment: What do you mean bu definition? because its the reason I got wrong answer.

Comment: $F(0)=\int_0^0 (2+sin^2(t)) dt=0$ @FirasAliAbdelGhani

Comment: @randomgirl Sorry, but I don't get it: why should $F'$ be equal to $f$? I'm certainly not using $f(x)=2+\sin x^2$, but the OP's definition.

Answer (score 3):

it is easier to use $$d \int_a^b f(x) \, dx = f(b)\, db - f(a) \, da.$$ in your case the lower limit is not changing; only the change in upper limit contributes to the change in the integral. therefore $$d\left(\int_0^{x^2 - 3x} 2 + \sin t^2\, dt\right) = \left(2 + \sin (x^2 - 3x)^2\right) d\left(x^2 - 3x\right) \to \\
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_0^{x^2 - 3x} 2 + \sin t^2\, dt\right) = \left(2 + \sin (x^2 - 3x)^2\right) \left(2x - 3\right) $$

Answer (score 1):

This is what you should get (see [Leibniz's integral rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule))

> $$ f'(x) =(2+\sin^2(x^2-3x))( 2x-3 ).  $$